# How to completely rename a batch of files

Tags: r

Goal : Currently the files in my directory are somewhat meaningless and I want to rename them to descriptive names.

Currently the names are garbage, for example

```
#list starting directory for all the files
startingDir <- "AllComplete/"
filez <- list.files(startingDir, pattern=".pdb", full.names = FALSE)
head(filez)

[1] "0398602d83ba805a.final.pdb" "0b369239e1e4cb15.final.pdb"
[3] "0f94c3d3d2a1011b.final.pdb" "118e6d6e8a8015dd.final.pdb"
[5] "1ff3a129dd268754.final.pdb" "231175d58ba732a9.final.pdb”
...
[46] "f3f6bccf1fb6d2f6.final.pdb”
```

I want to rename the files to a string of names that are in the same order that are more useful.

specifically the newNames should these:

```
[1] "ABI78961.1_cellulose_synthase_8_[Physcomitrella_patens]"                                     
 [2] "AAD20396.1_putative_cellulose_synthase_catalytic_subunit_[Arabidopsis_thaliana]"             
 [3] "ABI78958.1_cellulose_synthase_5_[Physcomitrella_patens]"                                     
 [4] "ADK77974.1_cellulose_synthase_A_[Griffithsia_monilis]"                                       
 [5] "AAM20487.1_cellulose_synthase-like_protein_[Arabidopsis_thaliana]”
...
[46] "ABP96902.1_cellulose_synthase_1_[Phytophthora_infestans]"
```

Both the file names and the new names are in the same order in the vector

I’ve tried file.rename but I don’t think I’ve use it correctly.

```
# get the list of files names
startingDir <- "AllComplete/"
filez <- list.files(startingDir, pattern=".pdb", full.names = FALSE)

#create my string of new names that I want in the same order from a data frame containing that information
newNames <- my_data$`# Description`

#try to rename
file.rename(from=filez, to=newNames)
```

Then I get the error

```
cannot rename file '0398602d83ba805a.final.pdb' to 'ABI78961.1_cellulose_synthase_8_[Physcomitrella_patens]', reason 'No such file or directory’
```

How could I go about solving this?

Comment: I would suggest that square brackets do not make for good file names. I would also suggest that rather than using file names, a better approach is to create a data frame of keys and values, where one column (the key) is the original file name and the second column is the descriptive `newNames`.

Comment: can't replicate error on linux.  What OS are you on?  Make sure you are in the right working directory.  What do you get if you type `file.exists(filez)`?  I suggest running `setwd(startingDir)` then try again